# How to extract a single Key value from a JSON file?

Tags: python

This is my output.json file:

```
{
    "ParsedResults": [
        {
            "TextOverlay": {
                "Lines": [],
                "HasOverlay": false,
                "Message": "Text overlay is not provided as it is not requested"
            },
            "TextOrientation": "0",
            "FileParseExitCode": 1,
            "ParsedText": "180 Grade IV\r\n\u0103\u021ar: Class VIII Pass\r\nwww.facebook.com, Since 2012\r\n",
            "ErrorMessage": "",
            "ErrorDetails": ""
        }
    ],
    "OCRExitCode": 1,
    "IsErroredOnProcessing": false,
    "ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": "343",
    "SearchablePDFURL": "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested."
}
```

I am trying to get the `ParsedText` value from this JSON file.

This is my the code I am using:

```
import json
    
f = open('output.json',)
data = json.load(f)
print(data['ParsedResults']['TextOverlay']['ParsedText'])
f.close()
```

Facing this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How to read that particular value from `ParsedText`, please guide. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

ParsedResults is not an object, it's a list

try this:

```
import json

f = open('output.json',)
data = json.load(f)
print(data['ParsedResults'][0]['ParsedText'])
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

> data['ParsedResults']  is a list, you need to use the index to parse, So you are getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

use data['ParsedResults'][0].

use the following,

```
import json
f = open('output.json',)
data = json.load(f)
print(data['ParsedResults'][0]['TextOverlay']['ParsedText'])
f.close()
```